# 2911 as default GW for Nexus

Tags: cisco-nexus-7k

(There was a previous question that resolved the VLAN issue.)

I have a section of topology where a 2911 is acting as an internal NAT router. (We don't have enough private IP addresses to give to all our lab servers and networking equipment. So we have our own reserved addresses that aren't routable across the corporate network).

The 2911 is using one private IP address to NAT lab IP addresses

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.16.25.94 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!

ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.16.25.1
!
access-list 1 permit any
!
!
!
control-plane
!
```

I have 16 Nexus switches, but I'm showing one as a sample here. (If I can get this going, the rest should be easy).

```
vlan 1,100,102-103,200

vrf context management

interface Vlan1

interface Vlan100
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.0.0.22/24

interface Vlan200
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.1.0.22/24

interface Ethernet1/1
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/40
  switchport access vlan 100


interface Ethernet1/48
  switchport mode trunk

interface Ethernet1/49
  switchport access vlan 200

interface Ethernet1/50
  switchport access vlan 200
```

While a Nexus can ping the default GW of each VLAN , it can't ping outside of the 2911 network.

```
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.765 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.571 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0.547 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=0.54 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms

--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.00% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.534/0.591/0.765 ms
2# ping 10.1.0.1
PING 10.1.0.1 (10.1.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.785 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.565 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0.557 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=0.532 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=0.538 ms

--- 10.1.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.00% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.532/0.595/0.785 ms

2# ping 192.16.25.1
PING 192.16.25.1 (192.16.25.1): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto 192.16.25.1 64 chars, No route to host
```

What am I missing to make NAT & Routing work? Also, is this just the Nexus management? Can hosts connected to the Nexus talk to outside already?

the 2911 can ping anything by the way.

[Update]

```
C(config)# vrf context management
C(config-vrf)# ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.1.0.1 (same result with 10.0.0.1)
C(config-vrf)# ping 192.16.25.94
PING 192.16.25.94 (192.16.25.94): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto 192.16.25.94 64 chars, No route to host
Request 0 timed out
ping: sendto 192.16.25.94 64 chars, No route to host
```

Comment: You should create a loopback for a test. Assign an address to it, set it up as an inside interface, and ping using it as a source.

Comment: You mean on 2911? I can ping anything using gig 0/2.100 or 2.200 as a source. That what you mean?

Comment: OK. I was just wanting to test to make sure that the NAT is functioning, and that works. What is the Nexus configuration for the default gateway?

Comment: That sir, is the question of the hour. Nexus doesn't seem to have "ip default-gateway" like catalyst. and I'm reading up on VRF management without luck. For now, I need the Nexus to act dumb and just be simple like catalyst. No L3/VRF/CEF or vPC.

Comment: It was pretty easy to find: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11282626/nx-7000-configuring-default-gateway

Comment: LOL, what did you use on google search?  "nx7k default gateway?" was stuck on https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11691736/cisco-nexus-default-gateway

Comment: I used `nx-os default gateway`. Also, I remember needing to use, on IOS switches, a default gateway, even with layer-2 switching. I found this as a recommendation:  
`vrf context management`    
`ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.0.0.1`

Comment: Updated post with no luck. If this is VRF thing, I'll have to think later. Would the end hosts at least have full connectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C(config)# vrf context management
>
> C(config-vrf)# ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.1.0.1

The issue appears to be that you've configured the default route in the Management VRF but you're pinging from outside of the Management VRF. Therefore, you're pings are failing.

If you want to set up a default route for VLANs100 & 200, you'll need to configure the default route in the main routing table. e.g:

> C(config)# ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.1.0.1

Note how I did not specify the management VRF before issuing the above command.

Answer (score 0):

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12918911/nexus-default-gateway

NAT generally doesn't like "any" as the source IP addresses.

Try modifying `any` to `10.0.0.0 0.0.1.255`.

I tend to use extended ACLs with `any` as the destination IP addresses, which NAT is fine with, but then you would need to update your NAT statement as well.

By the way, are you happy with setting up the management port or do you want to try the SVI? It may not make a difference but I have seen it not work many times with that.

For your Nexus switches, can you pick one of the SVIs on the Nexus and shut the other down? Then:

```
int vlan <x>
management

ip route 0.0.0.0/0 vlan <x> <router subinterface IP for vlan x>
```

don't put the default route in the management VRF.

I'm not sure whether technically this makes it L3 from a Nexus perspective, but as long as the client's default gateways are the router subinterface IP addresses, it shouldn't matter.

Like I say, I have not used Nexus, so it may not help, but it's worth a try.